# Does end iterator get update when inserting a new element?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

I cannot figure why I'm getting an error when running the following simple program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    std::vector<int> v{ 1,2,3,4,5 };
    std::vector<int>::iterator it1 = v.end();
    auto it_tmp = v.insert(v.end(), 6);
    std::vector<int>::iterator it2 = v.end();

    std::cout << (it1 == it2) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The iterators `it1` and `it2` are incompatible, so I was wondering what could possible be the issue. Iterators are incompatible if they belong to different containers, I would then assume in my case one of the two gets invalidated or something like that (I've also try to change `v.end` with `v.begin()` for both `it1` and `it2`, it doesn't make any difference).

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`it1 == it2` evaluates false because after this `auto it_tmp = v.insert(v.end(), 6);`, end iterator changes.

`std::vector::insert` inserts *before* the given iterator. Everything before the insertion point remains valid. Everything after it is invalidated. `it1` here is invalidated:

## [std::vector::insert](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert)

> Causes reallocation if the new size() is greater than the old
> capacity(). If the new size() is greater than capacity(), all
> iterators and references are invalidated. Otherwise, only the
> iterators and references before the insertion point remain valid. **The
> past-the-end iterator is also invalidated.**

Comment: What happens to the old one then?

Comment: @user8469759 added that to the answer

Comment: @user8469759 The past-the-end iterator is also invalidated

Comment: I've just tried to do `v.reserve(1000)`, still doesn't work.

Comment: @user8469759 even if you have enough space and nothing is allocated, an insertion to a vector always invalidates every iterator after the insertion point

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192868/discussion-between-ayxan-and-user8469759).